# How to check if windows sees a (micro HDMI) video port

Tags: windows-8.1, hdmi, intel-graphics, asus-laptop

I have an Asus T100TA and for some reason, micro HDMI output does not seem to work. So I've started wondering, does Windows even acknowledge the port exists? I can't see any suggestion of that anywhere.

So is there a place where I would *definitely* be able to see some proof of the port being recognized (if it's even true...)?

I have the latest Intel graphics driver supplied by Asus for this computer installed, running on Windows 8.1. The issue arose quite some time ago, I think after some Windows update in summer, but I had then given up on trying to fix it.

Comment: Have you looked in Device Manager?

Comment: @Excellll: I did, and I can't find anything there. But maybe I don't know what it's supposed to look like. There is a section on audio inputs and outputs there, but nothing like that for graphics. I can't find anything about WiDi there, either, but it does seem to be recognized (although I can't really test it for lack of a WiDi adapter).